# Compare to multiple values in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

im going to need multiple if statements comparing to the same couple elements, and was wondering if there was something along these lines i could do to make the code cleaner and easier.

Example would be that this function.

```
def test(num): 

    a = [1, 2, 3]

    if num == a : 
        return True

    else : 
        return False
```

would return

```
>>>test(1)
True
>>>test(2)
True
>>>test(5)
False
```

Instead of having to write the separate if statements for `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `in` operator

```
if num in a :
```

as in

```
def test(num): 
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    if num in a : 
        return True
    else : 
        return False
```

a work around would be (as suggested by Padraic)

```
 def test(num): 
        a = [1, 2, 3]
        return num in a
```

This would work because, The in operator compares if the LHS is present in the RHS and returns a boolean value respectively.

Also this is possible

```
test = lambda x:  num in [1, 2, 3]
```

That is all in a single line!

Comment: thanks! i cant believe i didnt think of that now

Comment: and how about `return (num in [1, 2, 3])` :)

Comment: @Bhargav, you don't need the parens.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But I needed the explanation! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in`, or check for the `index` and catch the error:

**`num in a` will check if the item `num` is in the list `a`.**

```
>>> 1 in [1, 2, 5]
True
>>> 3 in [1, 2, 5]
False
>>> 100 in range(101)
True
```

**`try` getting the index, and `except` to catch the `IndexError`:**

```
def isIn(item, lst):
    try:
        lst.index(item)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return False

>>> isIn(5, [1, 2, 5])
True
>>> isIn(5, [1, 2, 3])
False
```