# Simple looping if password

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, passwords

```
while True:
    look = input("Key : ")
    if look == "ksvbd956dmew1":
```

But instead of that and having a bunch of elifs can I do like

```
while True:
    look = input("Key : ")
    if look == "ksvbd956dmew1", "Otherpassword", "Otherpassword":
```

Then if the user types one of those passwords it lets them in. I wasn't sure what this was called as I am new to python so I couldn't search it up Hopefully someone could help me here :)

Comment: here is a hint, try searching for what the `in` keyword means in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare to multiple values in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372848/compare-to-multiple-values-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
passwordList = ("ksvbd956dmew1", "Otherpassword", "Otherpassword")
password = input("Please enter password : ")
while True:
    try:
            if password in passwordList:
                print("Password is Correct")
                break
            else:
                raise Exception

    except:
            print("Password is wrong")
            password = input("Please enter password : ")
```

Comment: Thanks it was just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    look = input("Key : ")
    if look in ("ksvbd956dmew1", "Otherpassword", "Otherpassword"):
        ...
```